# Database design - many-to-many relationship between three columns

Tags: database-design

I'm noob in database. So don't mind if its a silly question.This is used in my application and is the first one. I need a database design for it.

[image]

value 4 is dependent on the other value 1,2&3. even if one of the value changes the combination changes and the fourth value is affected. Each of the value 1,value 2,value 3 are independent on each other. Many-to-many relation between value 1,value 2 and value 2,value 3. value 4 is not derived or computed but a distinct value for all the combinations. So how can I design a database for it?